# Как правильно написать SQL-запрос на выборку из таблицы

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы:

1. Customers

```
_____________________________________
| C_id | Name |   Address    | City |
_____________________________________
|  1   | John | Borovay st   | Spb  |
_____________________________________
|  2   | Paul | Tverskaya st | Msk  |
_____________________________________
|  3   | Ivan | Bauman st    | Kzn  |
_____________________________________
```

2. Orders

```
________________________________
| O_id | O_no  | C_id  | Total |
________________________________
|  1   | 10298 |   2   |  157  |
________________________________
|  2   | 23791 |   2   |  268  |
________________________________
|  3   | 12375 |   1   |  984  |
________________________________
|  4   | 36571 |   1   |  235  |
________________________________
|  5   | 28972 |   13  |  427  |
________________________________
```

Нужно выбрать общую сумму (Total) всех заказов для пользователей из таблицы Customers с помощью SQL запроса. Как это сделать если внешний ключ 13 из таблицы Orders отсутствует в таблице Customers. И я не понимаю как этот ключ в принципе положить в Orders если при попытке INSERT возникает ошибка:

```
INSERT INTO orders
VALUES
(1, 10298, 2, 157),
(2, 23791, 2, 268),
(3, 12375, 1, 984),
(4, 36571, 1, 235),
(5, 28972, 13, 427);
```

> ERROR: ОШИБКА:  INSERT или UPDATE в таблице "orders" нарушает
> ограничение внешнего ключа "orders_u_id_fkey" DETAIL:  Ключ
> (c_id)=(13) отсутствует в таблице "customers".

Comment: Я конечно могу ошибаться, но вроде выглядит так как будто у вас из одной таблицы двнные удаляются не каскадно  и из-за этого вы попали в такую ситуацию

Comment: То есть у вас как-будто заказ сделал пользователь которого нет в базе. Выглядит как косяк проектирования бд

Comment: Сначала вставляете все записи в Customers и только после этого начинаете вставлять записи в Orders в которых упоминаются id из Customers. И разумеется убеждаетесь что все упоминаемые id действительно существуют (сейчас ошибка говорит о том, что вы пытаетесь вставить заказ который ссылается на не существующего Customer)

Comment: Зачем вы вставляете запись с customer 13 если его нет ?

Comment: `как этот ключ в принципе положить в Orders при попытке INSERT (в таблицу orders) возникает ошибка` , `Ключ (c_id)=(13) отсутствует в таблице "customers".` эммм? наверное добавить запись в таблицу customers?

Comment: вставляете пользователя с id=13 и все. Добавляете полю C_id d в Customers primary key, а C_id в Orders references Customers(C_id)  on delete cascade on update cascade и при инсерте в следующий раз сперва проверяйте что пользователь с таким id есть а потом уже вставляйте заказ

Comment: Прошу прощения за свою некомпетентность, просто так сформулирована задача, получается подвох в том что в Customers специально не записан ключ 13, соответственно нужно добавить в Customers заказчика с ключом 13 с помощью INSERT. Потом с помощью INSERT добавить его заказ в Orders и только потом SELECT SUM(total) FROM orders;  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала надо внести новую запись в таблицу Customers с C_id=13. Потом уже можно делать INSERT в orders.